# jQuery getting the value of the second through tenth td of the clicked tr in a table. I already have the first

Tags: jquery, click, html-table

```
                    $("#existcustomers tr").click(function () {
                        var td1 = $(this).children("td").first().text();
                        alert(td1);
                    });
```

I need the value of td2-td10 as well. I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. I tried using `.second()` in the same fashion but that seems to be breaking the programming. Does anyone know how this would be accomplished for the following td's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a specific cell by index, you can use :

```
$(this).children(":eq(1)")
```

To get the first 10 children, use :

```
$(this).children(":lt(10)")
```

If you want to get the content in separate cells of an array, you can do

```
var texts = $(this).children(":lt(10)").map(function(){return $(this).text()});
```

This makes an array like this :

```
["contentofcell1", "cell2", "3", "cell 4", "five", "six", "sieben", "otto", "neuf", "X"]
```

Comment: This was the magic code that I was looking for. Many thanks! $(this).children(":eq(1)").text();

Answer (score 2):

Use `eq(index)` to find it easly.

```
$("#existcustomers tr").click(function () {
    var td1 = $(this).children("td").first().text();
    var td2 = $(this).find("td").eq(2).text();
    var td10 = $(this).find("td").eq(10).text();
    alert(td1 + "-" + td2 + "-" + td10);
});
```

to get values of td2 - td10 range:

```
$("#existcustomers tr").click(function () {
    var td1 = $(this).children("td").first().text();
    var result = "";
    for(var i=2; i<=10; i++) {
        result = result + " - " + $(this).find("td").eq(i).text();
    }
    alert(td1 + result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).children("td").each(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
}
```

Will loop through all the `td`s.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#existcustomers tr").click(function() {
    var td1 = "";
    // To get values of td's between 2 and 10 we should search for
    // the td's greater than 1 and less than 11...
    $.each($(this).children("td:lt(11):gt(1)"),function() {
        td1 += $(this).text();
    });
    alert(td1);
});
```