# Get value of cell from table HTML and insert into Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ignite-ui, igcombo

I have some code that I am using to filter some user selections however I would like to use an existing html table as the datasource for the igcombo box. I need some jquery to select the "products" and "chargetypes" from the table and put them in an array to be used as a datasource for the igcombobox. Here is my code:

```html
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://igniteui.com/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
      <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/js/infragistics.lob.js"></script>
      <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
      <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
      <title>WebFOCUS Report</title>
      <style type="text/css"></style>
      <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    TABLE { border-collapse:collapse; }
    TD { vertical-align:top; padding-left:6pt; padding-right:6pt; }
    .x4 { font-family:TAHOMA; font-size:9pt; color:#424649; background-color:#FFFFFF;
     border-style: NONE; }
    .x9 { font-family:TAHOMA; font-size:9pt; color:#424649; background-color:#FFFFFF;
     border-top: 1.00pt SOLID #FFFFFF; border-bottom: NONE; border-right: NONE; border-left: NONE; }
    .x7_0 { font-family:TAHOMA; font-size:9pt; color:#424649; background-color:#FFFFFF;
     border-top: 1.00pt SOLID #FFFFFF; border-bottom: NONE; border-right: NONE; border-left: 1.00pt SOLID #FFFFFF; }
    .x7_1 { font-family:TAHOMA; font-size:9pt; color:#424649; background-color:#EAEBEC;
     border-top: 1.00pt SOLID #FFFFFF; border-bottom: NONE; border-right: NONE; border-left: 1.00pt SOLID #FFFFFF; }
    .x8_0 { font-family:TAHOMA; font-size:9pt; color:#424649; background-color:#FFFFFF;
     border-top: 1.00pt SOLID #FFFFFF; border-bottom: NONE; border-right: 1.00pt SOLID #FFFFFF; border-left: 1.00pt SOLID #FFFFFF; }
    .x8_1 { font-family:TAHOMA; font-size:9pt; color:#424649; background-color:#EAEBEC;
     border-top: 1.00pt SOLID #FFFFFF; border-bottom: NONE; border-right: 1.00pt SOLID #FFFFFF; border-left: 1.00pt SOLID #FFFFFF; }
    .x5 { font-family:TAHOMA; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#56A0D3;
     border-top: 1.00pt SOLID #FFFFFF; border-bottom: NONE; border-right: NONE; border-left: 1.00pt SOLID #FFFFFF; }
    .x6 { font-family:TAHOMA; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#56A0D3;
     border-top: 1.00pt SOLID #FFFFFF; border-bottom: NONE; border-right: 1.00pt SOLID #FFFFFF; border-left: 1.00pt SOLID #FFFFFF; }
    .x1 { font-family:TAHOMA; font-size:9pt; color:#424649; background-color:#FFFFFF; text-align:left;
     border-style: NONE; }
    .x2 { font-family:TAHOMA; font-size:11pt; font-weight:bold; color:#424649; background-color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center;
     border-style: NONE; }
    .x3 { font-family:TAHOMA; font-size:9pt; color:#424649; background-color:#FFFFFF; text-align:left;
     border-style: NONE; }
    -->
    </style>
      <script>
        $(function() {
          var dsCountry, dsCascTowns, dsCountryCascading,
            dsCountryCascading, dsStatesUSCascading, dsDistrictBGCascading;

          dsCountry = [{
            txtCountry: "3Delta Level 3",
            valCountry: "Ta"
          }, {
            txtCountry: "Account Updater",
            valCountry: "Au"
          }, {
            txtCountry: "DCC",
            valCountry: "Dc"
          }];

          dsCascDistrict = [{
            keyCountry: "Ta",
            txtDistrict: "ALL",
            valDistrict: "AL"
          }, {
            keyCountry: "Ta",
            txtDistrict: "3336",
            valDistrict: "3336"
          }, {
            keyCountry: "Ta",
            txtDistrict: "6064",
            valDistrict: "6064"
          }, {
            keyCountry: "Ta",
            txtDistrict: "6980",
            valDistrict: "6980"
          }, {
            keyCountry: "Ta",
            txtDistrict: "6081",
            valDistrict: "6081"
          }, {
            keyCountry: "Au",
            txtDistrict: "ALL",
            valDistrict: "AL"
          }, {
            keyCountry: "Au",
            txtDistrict: "3345",
            valDistrict: "3345"
          }, {
            keyCountry: "Au",
            txtDistrict: "3346",
            valDistrict: "3346"
          }, {
            keyCountry: "Au",
            txtDistrict: "6214",
            valDistrict: "6214"
          }, {
            keyCountry: "Dc",
            txtDistrict: "ALL",
            valDistrict: "AL"
          }, {
            keyCountry: "Dc",
            txtDistrict: "40",
            valDistrict: "40"
          }];

          dsCascTowns = [{
            keyDistrict: "NJ",
            textTown: "Atlantic City",
            valTown: "AtlanticCity"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "NJ",
            textTown: "Dover",
            valTown: "Dover"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "CA",
            textTown: "Los Angeles",
            valTown: "LosAngeles"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "CA",
            textTown: "San Francisco",
            valTown: "San Francisco"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "CA",
            textTown: "San Diego",
            valTown: "SanDiego"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "IL",
            textTown: "Chicago",
            valTown: "Chicago"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "NY",
            textTown: "New York",
            valTown: "NewYork"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "NY",
            textTown: "Buffalo",
            valTown: "Buffalo"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "FL",
            textTown: "Miami",
            valTown: " Miami"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "FL",
            textTown: "Orlando",
            valTown: "Orlando"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "SA",
            textTown: "Sofia",
            valTown: "Sofia"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "SA",
            textTown: "Pernik",
            valTown: "Pernik"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "PV",
            textTown: "Plovdiv",
            valTown: "Plovdiv"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "PV",
            textTown: "Asenovgrad",
            valTown: "Asenovgrad"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "V",
            textTown: "Varna",
            valTown: "Varna"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "V",
            textTown: "Kavarna",
            valTown: "Kavarna"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "V",
            textTown: "Balchik",
            valTown: "Balchik"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "Y",
            textTown: "Yambol",
            valTown: "Yambol"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "Y",
            textTown: "Kermen",
            valTown: "Kermen"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "Y",
            textTown: "Elhovo",
            valTown: "Elhovo"
          }, {
            keyDistrict: "Y",
            textTown: "Bolyarovo",
            valTown: "Bolqrovo"
          }, ];

          $(function() {

            $("#comboCountry").igCombo({
              textKey: "txtCountry",
              valueKey: "valCountry",
              dataSource: dsCountry,
              selectionChanged: function(evt, ui) {
                var filteredCascDistrict = [];
                if (ui.items && ui.items[0]) {
                  var itemData = ui.items[0].data;
                  if (itemData.valCountry == "US") {
                    $("#state").css("display", "none");
                    $("#district").css("display", "block");
                  } else {
                    $("#state").css("display", "none");
                    $("#district").css("display", "block");
                  }

                  filteredCascDistrict = dsCascDistrict.filter(function(district) {
                    return district.keyCountry == itemData.valCountry;
                  });
                }

                var $comboDistrict = $("#comboDistrict");
                $comboDistrict.igCombo("deselectAll", {}, true);
                $comboDistrict.igCombo("option", "dataSource", filteredCascDistrict);
                $comboDistrict.igCombo("dataBind");

                var disableChildCombo = filteredCascDistrict.length == 0;
                $comboDistrict.igCombo("option", "disabled", disableChildCombo);
              },
              itemsRendered: function(evt, ui) {
                ui.owner.deselectAll();
              }
            });

            $("#comboDistrict").igCombo({
              valueKey: "valDistrict",
              textKey: "txtDistrict",
              dataSource: [],
              disabled: true,
              filteringCondition: "startsWith",
              multiSelection: {
                enabled: true
              },
              selectionChanged: function(evt, ui) {
                var filteredCascTown = [];

                if (ui.items && ui.items[0]) {
                  var itemData = ui.items[0].data;

                  var filteredCascTown = dsCascTowns.filter(function(town) {
                    return town.keyDistrict == itemData.valDistrict;
                  });
                }

                var $comboTown = $("#comboTown");
                $comboTown.igCombo("deselectAll");
                $comboTown.igCombo("option", "dataSource", filteredCascTown);
                $comboTown.igCombo("dataBind");

                var disableChildCombo = filteredCascTown.length == 0;
                $comboTown.igCombo("option", "disabled", disableChildCombo);
              }
            });

            $("#comboTown").igCombo({
              valueKey: "valTown",
              textKey: "textTown",
              disabled: true
            });
          });
        });
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table cellpadding=1 style='margin-left:21pt;margin-right:18pt;margin-top:18pt;margin-bottom:18pt'>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <tr><td style='padding-left:0pt' colspan=4 class='x1'>
    <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td class='x2'>
    PRODUCT AND CHARGE TYPES</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP class='x3'>
    <a style='color:#424649'href="/ibi_apps/WFServlet.ibfs?IBIF_webapp=/ibi_apps&IBIC_server=EDASERVE&IBIWF_msgviewer=OFF&&IBIMR_drill=IBFS,RUNFEX,IBIF_ex,true&IBIF_ex=/WFC/Repository/Dillon/PRODUCT/Product_Charge_Type_Report.fex&CLICKED_ON=&WFFMT=EXL2K" TARGET="_new"><IMG SRC="/approot/epos/images/excel.png" border=0></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan=4 class='x4'>
    &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x5'>
    PRODUCT</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x5'>
    CHARGE TYPE</td>
    <td NOWRAP style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x5'>
    SHORT DESCRIPTION</td>
    <td NOWRAP style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x6'>
    LONG DESCRIPTION</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_0'>
    3Delta Level 3</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT class='x7_0'>
    3336</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_0'>
    3DELT AUTH</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x8_0'>
    3DELTA PER AUTH FEE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_0'>
    Account Updater</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT class='x7_0'>
    6214</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_0'>
    AU MNTHLY</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x8_0'>
    ACCOUNT UPDATER MONTHLY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_1'>
    Automated Customer Service</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT class='x7_1'>
    5037</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_1'>
    ACS PLUS S</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x8_1'>
    ACS PLUS SALE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_0'>
    Automated Customer Service</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT class='x7_0'>
    6146</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_0'>
    ACS SETUP</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x8_0'>
    ACS SETUP FEE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_1'>
    Automated Customer Service</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT class='x7_1'>
    5613</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_1'>
    ACS SALE</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x8_1'>
    ACS SOFTWARE - SALE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_0'>
    Automated Customer Service</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT class='x7_0'>
    6147</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_0'>
    ACS MO FEE</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x8_0'>
    ACS MONTHLY FEE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_1'>
    Automated Customer Service</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT class='x7_1'>
    5613</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_1'>
    ACS SALE</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x8_1'>
    ACS SOFTWARE - SALE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_0'>
    Automated Customer Service</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT class='x7_0'>
    6146</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_0'>
    ACS SETUP</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x8_0'>
    ACS SETUP FEE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_1'>
    Automated Customer Service</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT class='x7_1'>
    6147</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_1'>
    ACS MO FEE</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x8_1'>
    ACS MONTHLY FEE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_0'>
    Automated Customer Service</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT class='x7_0'>
    6147</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_0'>
    ACS MO FEE</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x8_0'>
    ACS MONTHLY FEE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_1'>
    Automated Customer Service</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT class='x7_1'>
    5037</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_1'>
    ACS PLUS S</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x8_1'>
    ACS PLUS SALE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_0'>
    Automated Customer Service</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT class='x7_0'>
    5613</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_0'>
    ACS SALE</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x8_0'>
    ACS SOFTWARE - SALE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_1'>
    Automated Customer Service</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT class='x7_1'>
    6943</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_1'>
    ACS FEE</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x8_1'>
    ACS FEE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_0'>
    Automated Customer Service</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT class='x7_0'>
    6146</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_0'>
    ACS SETUP</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x8_0'>
    ACS SETUP FEE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_1'>
    Automated Customer Service</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT class='x7_1'>
    5614</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x7_1'>
    ACS RENT</td>
    <td NOWRAP class='x8_1'>
    ACS SOFTWARE - RENTAL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td  class='x9'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td  class='x9'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td  class='x9'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td  class='x9'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
      <div class="group-container overHidden" id="before">
        <IFRAME class="frame" id=iframe1 name="iframe1" style="display: none" src="about:blank"></IFRAME>
        <form method="post" target="iframe1" action="SubmitToSomeFile" id="frm" accept-charset=UTF-8 name="frm">
          <div class="overHidden">
            <div class="comboGroup">
              <div>Product</div>
              <span id="comboCountry"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="comboGroup2">
              <div id="state">
                <br />
              </div>
              <div id="district">ChargeType</div>
              <span id="comboDistrict"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="comboGroup">
                    <div>Town</div>
                    <span id="comboTown"></span>
                </div> -->
          </div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <INPUT type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Run" id=button2 onClick="_submit_form();">
        </form>
        <!-- frame goes here -->
      </div>
      <div id="after" style="width:99%;border:gray 1px solid;display:none;background-color:#ccc;Padding:5px;height:100px;">Thank you</div>
      <!-- Some Content After the form. -->
      <script language="JavaScript">
        function _submit_form(){
       /* document.getElementById('before').style.display = 'none'; */
      /*  document.getElementById('after').style.display = 'block'; */
        var text1 = $("#comboCountry").igCombo("text");
        var text2 = $("#comboDistrict").igCombo("text");
     
     /* To handle text for one or multiple chargetypes */
        if (text2.indexOf(',') >= 0) {
        document.getElementById("after").innerHTML = "Your Product is " + text1 + "! Your ChargeTypes are " + text2;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("after").innerHTML = "Your Product is " + text1 + "! Your ChargeType is " + text2;
        
    }
     return true
    }
      </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Please respect the MINIMAL in the [mcve]  - also search for first and second td in google or here

Comment: Other duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759702/jquery-getting-the-value-of-the-second-through-tenth-td-of-the-clicked-tr-in-a-t